# GRUB won't boot, live CDs either

Tags: boot, grub, hardware, hard-disk, livecd

First, my computer crashed slowly, as if all the files were being deleted, then when I tried to reboot, GRUB just didn't show up.  I also tried to boot on a live CD but it doesn't work either (yes, I've checked the boot order.)

I suspect a HDD issue, yet I doubt it as live CDs don't work.
What to do?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like HDD issue to me too. It's possible that it's your controller rather than the drive (although a bad controller is likely to corrupt the drive too.

You should try booting up to a LiveCD *without* the HDD connected. If it works it's just a REALLY dead drive. If not, either the controller or BIOS has issues. Try flashing the latest BIOS and resetting factory defaults, then trying to LiveCD again.

Comment: BIOS is very unlikely to cause such problems. If it was a corrupted BIOS, the problems would begin suddenly. Also it would almost certainly display a checksum error and halt at that message.